# Remove double-quotes from generated query from ServiceStack.Ormlite

Tags: c#-4.0, ormlite-servicestack

Our DBA don't want us to use double quoted fields and tables in our queries (don't ask me the reason)... the problem is that ServiceStack.OrmLite double quote them all, and I don't have any idea on how disable this behaviour. **We are using ServiceStack.OrmLite Version 4.5.4.0**.

For example:

```
public class ClassA {
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

If we make a simple query like:

```
using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.Open())
{
   return db.LoadSingleById<ClassA>(id);
}
```

would generate:

```
select "ID", "Name" from "ClassA" where "ID" = @0
```

And this is what our dba want:

```
select ID, Name from ClassA where ID = @0
```

If anybody could help, I would apreciate a lot

PS I know I can write myself all queries, but there are too much code to change, so I'm trying to avoid this solution because it's too much time consuming at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my inspection of the source code, it appears that this cannot be changed out of the box.

When ORMLite builds its query, it grabs the column name and wraps it in quotation marks. See here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs#L384

An alternative would be to create a new `OrmLiteDialectProvider` that inherits whichever provider you are using (e.g., SQL Server, Oracle, etc), and override one of the following methods:

- `GetQuotedColumnName(string columnName)`
- `GetQuotedName(string name)`

Overriding either of those to exclude the quotation marks would get you what you're looking for.